# My question is about a code i have described but it didn't work

Tags: python, pycharm

SUMMER OF '69: Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers.¶

I have tried to use the pop method but it didn't work. I want to know why.

```
def summer_69(arr):
    num=(6,7,8,9)
    if num not in arr:
        return sum(arr)
    if num in arr:
        arr.pop(num)
        return sum(arr)

print(summer_69([4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```

I am getting the whole sum like in this one I am getting like 39.

Comment: Even if the `in` would work here, it is incorrect, since a sequence `4,6,0,9,7` will be `11`...

Comment: Why do you expect the above to work by the way?

Comment: `num` is a tuple and you are checking if it is inside a list of ints, so the first condition is met and the `sum` is returned

Comment: Please improve your title to be more descriptive.

Comment: Lots of things you need to think about in order to do what you want. a) Pop doesn't work the way you have coded it as an answer below states, b) You assuming that a 6 will always be followed by 7, 8, 9, but your question doesn't state that. c) You don't iterate at all. How would you deal with [1,6,1,9,2,6,3,9] - it can't be done without a loop d) Even when you do iterate over a list, it's probably not a great idea to pop numbers out of the list you're iterating over. A safer idea would be to iterate over a new list and append the values that you do want in your answer and skip the others

Comment: Before anyone else jumps on point c) above - without regex, but I'm assuming that's not in scope...

Comment: Is it possible to please fix the title. I think at least half of the questions here deal with persons that wrote some code that did not end up producing the expected result. That's not very "descriptive".

Answer (score 0):

Pop removes the item at a specified index.  Max index in your array is 5 (4 has index 0).
I recommend finding the index of 6 via

```
arr.index(6)
```

Not efficient, but you can then repeatedly pop that index until it becomes 9, (and popping once more if "extending to" means including the 9).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this i will suggest you to use a single loop as it will be more efficient. Use single loop and keep adding number to sum until 6 is encountered. As soon as 6 comes skip the numbers till a 9 occurs. Again start to add numbers to sum. Runs in O(n).

i=0

Sum =0

While i < length:

```
If a[i] == 6:

     While i < length and a[i] != 9:

         i += 1

Else:

    Sum += a[i]

i += 1
```

return Sum